# how to display hide and show select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I google a lot for my requirement.So i am posting this question.
       my requirement is when a user select a value from dropdown based on that value a div to be displayed. But in default all the divs with values to be displayed.

here is my code:

```
<select name="lab_1" id="title" >
  <option value="All" onclick="showAll();" >All</option>
  <option value="one" onclick="showOther();">One</option>
  <option value="two" onclick="showOther();">Two</option>    
</select>
<div id="All" >
  hiihdhfhdf
  <div id="otherTitle" style="display:none;" >
    select
  </div>
  <div id="otherTitle2" style="display:none;" >
    ramsai
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$('#title').change(function() {
    var all= $("#All").val();
    alert('hi');
    if(all==""){
        $("#otherTitle").show();
        $("#otherTitle2").show();
      }
      else if (this.value == "one") {
        $("#otherTitle").show();
        $("#otherTitle2").hide();
      }
      else if (this.value=="two"){
        $("#otherTitle2").show();
        $("#otherTitle").hide();
      }     
    });
    });


</script>
</body>
```

Here with above code when i click all my divs are not displaying but when i go to one or two options it is showing all the values.
I have 42 divs is there any other solution for all those divs in jquery or below mentioned are the only solutions for that

Thank you in advance

Ramsai

Comment: with this i am using php code also but i didnt gave that one in the question so i put the tag as php

Comment: `div` elements (`#All`) don't have a value, so `$("#All").val()` will **always** return an empty string and `all=="` will **always** be **true**. I don't understand what you are trying to do with the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="lab_1" id="title" >
<option value="All" onclick="show(this.value);" >All</option>
<option value="one" onclick="show(this.value);" >One</option>
<option value="two" onclick="show(this.value);" >Two</option>
</select>
```

Now your JavaScript will look like this :

```
<script>
function show(val){

  if(val=="All"){

     document.getElementById("otherTitle").style.visibility="";
     document.getElementById("otherTitle2").style.visibility="";

 }elseif(val=="one"){

     document.getElementById("otherTitle").style.visibility="";
     document.getElementById("otherTitle2").style.visibility="collapse";

 }elseif(val=="two"){

   document.getElementById("otherTitle").style.visibility="collapse";
   document.getElementById("otherTitle2").style.visibility="";
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hxadj/

There were a few extra things in the code that didn't need to be there.  Also you were testing for the value of All. I'm not sure why, what you needed was the value of the select which was done with (this.value == X)

```
$(function() {
$('#title').change(function() {
if(this.value == "All"){
    $("#All").show();        
    $("#otherTitle").show();
    $("#otherTitle2").show();
  }
  else if (this.value == "one") {
    $("#All").hide();          
    $("#otherTitle").show();
    $("#otherTitle2").hide();
  }
  else if (this.value=="two"){
    $("#All").hide();          
    $("#otherTitle2").show();
    $("#otherTitle").hide();
  }     
});
});
```

**UPDATE**

Link here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hxadj/1/

HTML:

```
<select name="lab_1" id="title" >
<option value="All">All</option>
<option value="otherTitle">One</option>
<option value="otherTitle2">Two</option>
</select>

<div id="All" class="togglers">hiihdhfhdf</div>
<div id="otherTitle" class="togglers">select</div>
<div id="otherTitle2" class="togglers">ramsai</div>
```

JS

```
    $(function() {
    $('#title').change(function() {
    var divName = this.value;
    if(this.value == "All"){    
        $(".togglers").show();
    }else{      
        $(".togglers").hide();
        $("#"+divName).show();           
      }     
    });
});
```

This should do it.  Bascially your select option values have to correspond to the div ID's.  Then you do not need to go in and hardcode a show() or hide() rule for each one.

Comment: I have 40 divs default all is there when page loads. if anybody selects the item in the list then only that div values to be displayed. This is my exact requirement. Is there any better way to do apart from this.......

Answer (score 0):

Or again:

```
$('#title').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $('#otherTitle, #otherTitle2').not('#'+id).hide();
    $('#'+id).children().show();         
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G7rNR/)